# Wxpython weird display error when modifying GridBagSizer

Tags: python, wxpython

In the following program I have a sort of Tetris running. I'm using WxPython to display it. The blocks are moved with commands, indicating a lettre, a number and < or >. Ex: A7>. This means that the block in position A7 will move in the direction indicated by the arrow. You add it in the "Jugada:" TextCtrl, and it instantly executes when introduced. As I programmed with pure python the "moving" part, it works well. But the display function is the problem. The first time I use it it works perfectcly:

[image]

But when I use it a second time it displays this:
[image]

When I change the window size, everything goes back to normal but there are numbers that display in a way I don't understand:
[image]

Here is the whole code, but the part of the program that with wxpython is the one from class MenuFrame(wx.Frame). The blocks are list with the info [x_position,length,colour,y_position].

```py
import wx
import itertools
alto=12
def superponen(primero,otro):
    if (otro[0] <= primero[0] < otro[0] + otro[1]):
        return True
    elif (otro[0] <= primero[0] + primero[1] - 1 < otro[0] + otro[1]):
        return True
    elif (primero[0] <= otro[0] < primero[0] + primero[1]):
        return True
    elif (primero[0] <= otro[0] + otro[1] - 1 < primero[0] + primero[1]):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def bajar(bloque):
    sobre_nada=True
    if bloque[3] == 12:
        sobre_nada = False
    for bloque_que_probar in bloques:
        if bloque_que_probar[3] == bloque[3] + 1:
            if superponen(bloque, bloque_que_probar) == True:
                sobre_nada = False
    while sobre_nada==True:
        bloque[3]+=1
        if bloque[3] == 12:
            sobre_nada=False
        for bloque_que_probar in bloques:
            if bloque_que_probar[3] == bloque[3] + 1:
                if superponen(bloque, bloque_que_probar) == True:
                    sobre_nada=False


def ordenar_alturas(bloque):
    return bloque[3]


def bloques_bajados():
    global bloques
    for elemento in sorted(bloques,key=ordenar_alturas, reverse=True):
        bajar(elemento)


def entrada_a_bloque(codigo):
    resultado=[]
    leng=0
    x=0
    #AAabb b a
    for i in range(len(codigo)):
        leng += 1
        if i+1!=len(codigo):
            if codigo[i]==" ":
                x+=1
                leng=0
                continue

            if codigo[i]!=codigo[i+1]:
                if ord(codigo[i])==65 or ord(codigo[i])==97:
                    resultado.append([x,leng,"#",1])
                elif ord(codigo[i])==66 or ord(codigo[i])==98:
                    resultado.append([x,leng,"$",1])
                else:
                    resultado.append([x, leng, "%", 1])
                x+=leng
                leng=0
        else:
            if codigo[i]==" ":
                x+=1
                leng=0
                continue
            if ord(codigo[i]) == 65 or ord(codigo[i]) == 97:
                resultado.append([x, leng, "#", 1])
            elif ord(codigo[i]) == 66 or ord(codigo[i]) == 98:
                resultado.append([x, leng, "$", 1])
            else:
                resultado.append([x, leng, "%", 1])
    return resultado


def bloque_puede_mover(jugada, bloque_movido):
    y = "ABCDEFGHIJKL".index(jugada[0]) + 1
    sentido=jugada[2]
    en_misma_fila = []
    for bloque in bloques:
        if bloque[3]==y and bloque!=bloque_movido:
            en_misma_fila.append(bloque)
    if (bloque_movido[0]==0 and sentido=="<") or (bloque_movido[0]+bloque_movido[1]==10 and sentido==">"):
        return False
    for bloc in en_misma_fila:
        if sentido=="<":
            if bloc[0]+bloc[1]-1 == bloque_movido[0]-1:
                return False
        else:
            if bloc[0]==bloque_movido[0]+bloque_movido[1]:
                return False
    return True
def sintaxis_correcta(decision):
    if decision == "---":
        return True
    if len(decision) < 3 or len(decision)>3:
        return False
    if decision[0] not in "ABCDEFGHIJKL":
        return False
    if decision[1] not in map(str,range(10)):
        return False
    direccion = decision[2]
    if direccion != "<" and direccion != ">":
        return False
    return True
def bloque_seleccionado(decision):
    y = "ABCDEFGHIJKL".index(decision[0]) + 1
    x = int(decision[1])
    for bloque in bloques:
        if bloque[3]==y and bloque[0] <=x < bloque[0] + bloque[1]:
            return bloque
    return False
def correcto(jugada):
    if sintaxis_correcta(jugada) == False:
        print("Error de sintaxis en jugada")
        return False
    bloque_mover=bloque_seleccionado(jugada)
    if bloque_mover == False:
        print("No hay ningún bloque en esa celda")
        return False
    if bloque_puede_mover(jugada, bloque_mover) == False:
        print("El bloque no puede moverse en esa dirección")
        return False
    return bloque_mover

def jugar(block,jugada):
    while bloque_puede_mover(jugada, block):
        if jugada[2]=="<":
            block[0]-=1
        else:
            block[0]+=1

def eliminar_lineas():


    global bloques,puntuacion
    se_ha_roto=False
    for y in range(12):
        linea=[]
        for bloc in bloques:
            if bloc[3]==y+1:
                linea.append(bloc)
        suma_longitudes = 0
        for bloque_analizado in linea:
            suma_longitudes += bloque_analizado[1]
        if suma_longitudes == 10:
            color = linea[0][2]
            mismo_color = True
            for bloque in linea:
                if bloque[2] != color:
                    mismo_color = False
            if mismo_color == True:
                for bloque in bloques:
                    puntuacion += bloque[1]
                bloques = []
            else:
                puntuacion += 10
                for bloque in linea:
                    bloques.remove(bloque)
            se_ha_roto = True
    return se_ha_roto


#with open(input("Fichero de filas iniciales: "),"r") as archivo:
with open("D:/codigos.txt", "r") as archivo:
    data=archivo.read()
    archivo=data.split("\n")
bloques=[]
puntuacion=0

altura = 12
i=1

class MenuFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        global bloques
        # begin wxGlade: CalculatorFrame.__init__
        # kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.SetTitle("Deslizador")
        self.Center()

        self.half_sizer = wx.SplitterWindow(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.settings = wx.Panel(self.half_sizer)
        self.grid_side = wx.Panel(self.half_sizer)
        # self.grid_side.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        self.half_sizer.SetMinimumPaneSize(130)
        # self.half_sizer.SetSashPosition(100)
        self.half_sizer.SplitVertically(self.settings, self.grid_side)

        self.options_separator = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.fichero_separator = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label_fichero = wx.StaticText(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "Fichero: ")
        self.fichero_separator.Add(self.label_fichero, 0)

        self.control_fichero = wx.TextCtrl(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.fichero_separator.Add(self.control_fichero, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.options_separator.Add(self.fichero_separator, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.abr_fich = wx.Button(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "Abrir fichero")
        self.options_separator.Add(self.abr_fich, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.nuev_part = wx.Button(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "Nueva partida")
        self.options_separator.Add(self.nuev_part, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sep_n_filas = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label_n_filas = wx.StaticText(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "N° Filas:")
        self.sep_n_filas.Add(self.label_n_filas, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        self.spin_n_filas = wx.SpinCtrl(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, min=3, max=100, initial=12)
        self.sep_n_filas.Add(self.spin_n_filas, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.options_separator.Add(self.sep_n_filas, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.sep_jugadas = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.label_jugada = wx.StaticText(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "Jugada: ")
        self.sep_jugadas.Add(self.label_jugada, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)

        self.control_jugada = wx.TextCtrl(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.control_jugada.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT,self.game)
        self.sep_jugadas.Add(self.control_jugada, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.options_separator.Add(self.sep_jugadas, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.label_lista = wx.StaticText(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "Lista de jugadas:")
        self.options_separator.Add(self.label_lista, 0)

        self.lista = wx.ListBox(self.settings)
        self.options_separator.Add(self.lista, 10, wx.EXPAND)

        font = wx.Font(20, family=wx.FONTFAMILY_MODERN, style=0, weight=90, underline=False, faceName="",
                       encoding=wx.FONTENCODING_DEFAULT)
        self.label_puntos = wx.StaticText(self.settings, wx.ID_ANY, "PTOS: 0")
        self.label_puntos.SetFont(font)
        self.options_separator.Add(self.label_puntos, 0, wx.CENTER)

        self.settings.SetSizer(self.options_separator)
        self.tabla = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        nuevos = entrada_a_bloque(archivo[0])
        for nuevo_bloque in nuevos:
            #for nuevo_bloque in [[1,3,"A",12]]:
            bloques.append(nuevo_bloque)
        self.draw_table(bloques, self)



        self.grid_side.SetSizer(self.tabla)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()


    def draw_table(self, blocks,parent):
        global altura
        parent.tabla.Clear(True)
        #parent.tabla = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)
        for a in range(altura):
            text_add = wx.StaticText(parent.grid_side, wx.ID_ANY, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[a])
            parent.tabla.Add(text_add, wx.GBPosition(a, 0), wx.GBSpan(1, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
            try:
                parent.tabla.AddGrowableRow(a)
            except wx._core.wxAssertionError:
                pass
        for b in range(1,11):
            text_add = wx.StaticText(parent.grid_side, wx.ID_ANY, str(b))
            parent.tabla.Add(text_add, wx.GBPosition(12, b), wx.GBSpan(1, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
            try:
                parent.tabla.AddGrowableCol(b)
            except wx._core.wxAssertionError:
                pass
        for c in blocks:
            block = wx.Panel(self.grid_side,style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
            if c[2]=="#":
                block.SetBackgroundColour("green")
            elif c[2]=="$":
                block.SetBackgroundColour("blue")
            else:
                block.SetBackgroundColour("red")
            parent.tabla.Add(block, wx.GBPosition(c[3]-1, c[0]+1), wx.GBSpan(1, c[1]), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        parent.grid_side.SetSizer(parent.tabla)
    def game(self,evt):
        global altura, bloques, puntuacion, i, archivo,frame
        mov=frame.control_jugada.GetValue()
        if sintaxis_correcta(mov) and correcto(mov):
            parent=frame
            bloque=correcto(mov)
            jugar(bloque,mov)
            #parent.draw_table(bloques,parent)
            caida = True
            while caida:
                bloques_bajados()
                #parent.draw_table(bloques,parent)
                caida = eliminar_lineas()
                #parent.draw_table(bloques,parent)
            for bloque in bloques:
                if bloque[3] == 1:
                    print("FIN DE LA PARTIDA")
                    exit()
            nuevos = entrada_a_bloque(archivo[i])
            for nuevo_bloque in nuevos:
                bloques.append(nuevo_bloque)
            parent.draw_table(bloques, parent)
            i+=1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    global frame
    app = wx.App()
    frame=MenuFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")

    app.MainLoop()
```

Here you have the text inside the D:/codigos.txt file:

```
ABCcBAaB c
ABbBb BAa
 AB a  A B
A  Aa B A
BB  Aaaa
A B bBAABB
AAa AB AAA
  BBBA  B
BbBBBABb b
 a  aaa  A
Bb BbAAAaa
B AAABAB
ABb b  ABB
AABbb  a A
BBb AAA AB
AaaaBbb aa
BAaABBBB A
AB AAaaaBb
 BAAB B bA
BbBA AaAAa
AAA bbAAAA
B bBAAa  B
AaaA  a b
```

I did a test: I didn't display when oppening the window the blocks. This had the same bug, excluding the possibility of an error while clearing the chart.

Comment: You will have to fix your posted code. It doesn't run and my attempts to fix it, display a blank frame.

Comment: After guessing a value to represent the contents of `D:/codigos.txt` (`[["A","4","5","8", "9"]]`), for the program `not` to fall over immediately, I have no idea how to replicate your issue. How are we supposed to run this to see the error? Please try to put yourself in our position, we shouldn't have to guess, otherwise people will simply move on to another question.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new at SO. Thank you for correcting me and sorry for the inconvienience.

Comment: One last time, how do we replicate the problem? Define `there is a weird display` and `numbers that display in a way I don't understand`. How do we use `the function` for the `second time` and what is that function.

Comment: I hope tha it hepls you. Sorry, I'm pretty dumb and I don't know how you would understand what was happnning. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in your re-use of the `draw_table` function, which while it clears the sizer, does not clear the existing blocks. It simply creates new ones. I am quite happy to be incorrect but I think that you should either create a complete set of blocks and then simply colour them if they are in use, or re-draw the entire block panel each time. This does involve a major re-think but should make life easier for the future. Off topic, you are missing `N` in your height range and you are confused about the use of `parent`. Those items are all part of `self`.

Comment: I don't think so. If I use ```clear()``` without drawing anything afterwards, it doesn't display anything. So I assume the blocks have been deleted. Also, if after cleaning it I add something, it correctly addds itsself and there isn't any problem

Comment: And it wouldn't explain the first display, before refreshing the frame size.